# Как исправить ошибку в коде? ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

Tags: python

```
import os

def makeFolders():
    if os.path.exists(r'C:\hesoyam8927163'):
        print(0/0)
    else:
        os.makedirs(r'C:\hesoyam8927163\Chrome')
        os.makedirs(r'C:\hesoyam8927163\Opera')
        os.makedirs(r'C:\hesoyam8927163\Firefox')
        os.makedirs(r'C:\hesoyam8927163\SystemInformation')
        os.makedirs(r'C:\hesoyam8927163\TxtFilesFromDesktop')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 28, in <module>
  File "modules\others\folder.py", line 10, in makeFolders
    print(0/0)
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Comment: а зачем вы делите на 0?

Comment: удалите print(0/0)

Comment: @СергейШ, ну тогда уж заменить на `pass` a лучше в условие поставить `not` и перенести создание папок из блока `else`

Comment: print('0/0') тоже вариант :)